# I m working on a problem which state that $(n+1/n)^n>n$ and $n\geq 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have to prove that $(n+1/n)^n>=n$ and $n\geq 3$
What I did is : we know that $x+1/x\geq 2$
So $n+1/n\geq 2$

And then $(n+1/n)^n\geq 2^n$ and we know that $2^n\geq n$

So $(n+1/n)^n\geq 2^n\geq n$

Comment: That's correct, but are you sure the question isn't to prove that $(1+1/n)^n \ge n$ for $n \ge 3$?

Comment: Yeah very sure .

Comment: It seems even more trivial.   $n+ \frac 1n > n$ and and so $(n+\frac 1n)^n \ge(n+\frac 1n)^3 > n+\frac 1n > n$.  Ummm.... are you sure you stated the question correctly?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I don't see the difference between what you wrote and what the OP wrote.  (Unless it is the "for" rather than the "and".  The "and" makes the statement just false.  If $n =0, 1, 2$ then $n\ge 3$ is false.... but I was flexible in interpretation and assumed the OP meant "for")

Comment: How can i send you a picture of the exercise.

Comment: Corrc:∀n>=3 not and

Comment: Please correct in the question then ...

Comment: @fleablood You don't see the difference between $(1+1/n)^n$ and $(n+1/n)^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier to just use the fact that $\frac{1}{n}>0$ and, hence,
$$\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n>n^n>n$$